# Javascript DateTime toString issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to convert a Date to String with the following function:

```
   Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function () {
        this.setHours(this.getHours() - 2);
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
        var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd = this.getDate().toString();
        var hh = this.getHours().toString();
        var mm1 = this.getMinutes().toString();
        return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]) + ' ' + (hh[1] ? hh : "0" + hh[0]) + ':' + (mm1[1] ? mm1 : "0" + mm1[0]);
    };
```

I use this line of code to test my convert method:

```
(value.lastConnectedAt == null ? emptyvalue : value.lastConnectedAt + " + " + new Date(value.lastConnectedAt).yyyymmdd())
```

I'm getting some really wierd results:

```
2014-06-23T08:43:42Z + 2014-43-23 08:43
```

The month is totally wrong, and the 2 hours arn't added. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Your code is working as expected, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zvam3xqx/1/) Check value of `value.lastConnectedAt`

Comment: i run your code it is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ca1La3mg/
the -2 hours arn't removed. Why?

Comment: I entered in your code almost exactly, and it is working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/nr6urfce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the explanation of your problem:

- you get month = 43 instead of 06 because most probably you had a bug in a version that is different to the one posted where you had mm1 instead of mm[1] ; so you get month = minutes = 43
- you get hours = 08 instead of your expected 06 most probably because your PC is on a timezone with UTC+02. getHours / setHours are expressed in local time. Use setUTCHours / getUTCHours instead

Comment: Great spot with the variable name, +1. Definitely a timezone issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own function, there's a javascript function that will convert date and time to string for you:

```
alert(new Date().toString())
```

output:

```
"Thu Aug 21 2014 12:20:38 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"
```

Comment: That's not yyyyddmm format though, is it? [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) would be a better choice, but isn't widely supported (....by IE)